# Performance regarding storing entire objects as parameters to other objects

Tags: c#, memory

I have a system where `Object A` can at will produce `Object B`. One `Object A` can produce any number of `Object B`, and there are multiple `Object A`'s.

It is useful in my program to know WHICH `Object A` produced which `Object B` (for various reasons). Currently, whenever an `Object B` is created, I just store the `Object A` that created it as a parameter inside `Object B`. But this doesn't feel right to me.

**Question 1:** Is there a way to store simply a reference to the correct `Object A` inside the `Object B`, instead of the whole object? Or is that actually what's happening anyways?

**Question 2:** Is doing it the way I am now inefficient for memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:**

Yes it is possible. You can pass a reference to creator object e.g. by constructor. *It could be also by public property setter or public field but I would recommend to use constructor.*

```
public class ObjectB
{
    public ObjectA Parent {get; private set;}

    public ObjectB(ObjectA parent)
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
    }
}

public class ObjectA
{
    private ObjectB GetNewObjectB()
    {
         return new ObjectB(this);
    }
}
```

**Question 2:**

Object reference takes `4bytes/8bytes` on `32bit/64bit OS`. So you can roughly imagine the additional memory consumption and determine, if it is an issue for you (*IMHO it would not be an issue for most of the applications*).

Comment: This structure is perfect and will suit my needs excellently! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Yes - if you have

```
class A {}

class B
{
  A creator;
}
```

then the 'creator' reference is just that - a pointer to the object instance rather than a copy of the content itself.

Question 2: I don't think I have enough information to answer this - if you need the reference stored in B then its not inefficient. You might want to turn it into a WeakReference if you are happy for it to become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are reference types, so if your class `B` has a field of type class `A` then only a reference to the instance of `A` is stored in the field, not a copy of the entire object.

```
class B
{
    //creator is a reference to the instance of A which created this instance
    private A creator;
}
```